# Dom Freezes after ng-repeat event finishes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, dom, angularjs-digest

I have been working on this problem for several weeks and have tried several scenarios to fix it.

**First the problem**:

We have an angular application that has some major performance issues (lag, freezeing dom, slow to respond, etc).  Currently we have many nested ng-repeats iterating over an array.
I made an angular directive to create an 'alert' when the largest and longest ng-repeat finishes.

The ng-repeat finishes in a few seconds (the pop-up) pops up to confirm it.  And I can see the rows generated from the ng-repeat appear on the DOM.
**Weird part...ahead :** so now the DOM has rendered, and the ng-repeat end event fired.  The strange part is this is the slowest part of the page.  In Windows Task Manager under chrome, I can see that the memory for my browser instance is consitently climbing to far above 250,000kb, and my cpu usage is around 25.

The page is now frozen and I cannot open up more tabs or exapand more ng-repeats.  EVen after waiting 5+ min the page is very slow to respond with a delay time of at least 5 seconds.

---

**Things I have tried:**

1. Batarang, and Angular profiler.  I have minimized some watchers and added many one-way bindings.  this does little to nothing to help with the speed.
2. Removing the big object (from the ng-repeat) does make the page much faster, but it breaks the page.  So this tells me the problem is due to the size of object? Right?
3. I currently broke my ng-repeat into a directive, and am handling it in there.  It is still very slow.

---

**Final Questions:**

Does anyone have any idea why my application is slow (practically frozen) AFTER the ng-repeat finishes?  Also, does anyone know why once my ng-repeat fires off, my chrome memory resource usage climbs up and up until i get a 'Oops, chrome is not responding window'.  (Ive used the MemoryProfiler and I am pretty sure its not a memory leak.)

*Image 1 is directly after the DOM render of ng-repeat.
*Image 2 is taken 5 min after Image1 was taken.  The DOM has been frozen and immovable the whole time. ** Note the higher memory usage.**

[image: Slow Image 2]
[image: High Resource Usage]

[image: Examination of the problem]

Image 3 is a close up examination of the problem from Chrome Dev Tools.

---

Someone asked me to post some code, originally i wasnt going to post my code because its pretty large and idk how helpful it will be:
(I have other elements on the dom, this is just the problem code that makes it very slow. Repeating over writerRateConfig causes the lag.)

````

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="rateConfiguration in writerRateConfig track by $index">
        <!--<tbody ng-repeat="rateConfiguration in  writerSkinnyRate  track by $index">-->
       <tr ng-repeat="rate in ::rateConfiguration.rates">

                <td class="one-percent no-wrap centered">
                    <span ng-show="writer.controlled && $index == 0" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <button ng-disabled="licenseDetail != 2" securitydisable actions="LicenseDetailsIncludeExclude" class="btn btn-default btn-icon narrow" data-toggle="modal" ui-sref="SearchMyView.DetailLicense.StepsModal.WritersIsIncluded({config:rate,files:licenseAttachments,recording:recording,writer:writer,product:product,modalSize:'sm',rate:rateConfiguration })">
                            <span class="icon include" ng-show="rate.writerRateInclude"></span>
                            <span class="icon exclude" ng-show="!rate.writerRateInclude"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="fifteen-percent"><span ng-show="$index == 0"><span ng-class="rate.configuration_id | returnConfigurationIcon"></span><span ng-bind="rate.configuration_name"></span><span ng_if="rate.configuration_upc">(<span ng-bind="rate.configuration_upc"></span>)</span></span></td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-show="writer.controlled && $index == 0" title="{{rate.writersConsentType.description}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">
                        <button ng-disabled="!buttons.writerConsentBtn" securitydisable actions="LicenseDetailWriterConsent" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" ui-sref="SearchMyView.DetailLicense.StepsModal.WritersConsent({config:rate,files:licenseAttachments,recording:recording,writer:writer,product:product,modalSize:'md' })">
                            <span ng-bind="rate.writersConsentType.writersConsentType"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="fifteen-percent top">
                    <span ng-show="$index == 0">
                        <span ng-repeat="status in ::rateConfiguration.specialStatusList" class="badge">
                            <span ng-if="status.lU_SpecialStatuses"><span ng-bind="status.lU_SpecialStatuses.specialStatus"></span></span>
                            <span ng-if="!status.lU_SpecialStatuses"><span ng-bind="status.specialStatus"></span></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="fifteen-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == true"><span ng-show="$index == 0"><span ng-bind="rate.rateType.rateType"></span></span></td>
                <td class="fifteen-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == false"><span ng-show="$index == 0">N/A</span></td>
                <td class="five-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == false">N/A</td>
                <td class="five-percent centered" ng-if="writer.controlled == true" ng-show="writer.statPrcentageVisible == true"><span ng-bind="rate.percentOfStat"></span></td>
                <td class="ten-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == true" ng-show="writer.escalatedRateVisible == true"><span ng-bind="rate.escalatedRate"></span></td>
                <td class="five-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == false">N/A</td>
                <td class="five-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == true" ng-show="writer.escalatedRateVisible == true"><span ng-bind="rate.rate"></span></td>
                <td class="five-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == true"><span ng-bind="rate.proRataRate"></span></td>
                <td class="five-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == false">N/A</td>
                <td class="five-percent" ng-if="writer.controlled == true"><span ng-bind="rate.perSongRate"></span></td>
                <td class="ten-percent centered" ng-if="writer.controlled == false">N/A</td>
                <!--Display License Date, Signed Date or Effective Date-->
                <td class="ten-percent" ng-show="writer.controlled == true && $index==0"><span ng-bind="rate.licenseDate | timezone | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></span></td>

                <td class="ten-percent centered" ng-show="writer.controlled == true">
                    <span ng-show="$index==0">
                        <button ng-disabled="paidQuarterDisabled" securitydisable actions="LicenseDetailsPaidQuarter" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ui-sref="SearchMyView.DetailLicense.StepsModal.PaidQuarter({licenseId:licenseDetail.licenseId,config:rate,recording:recording,writer:writer,product:product, modalSize:'sm' })">
                            <span ng-bind="rateConfiguration.paidQuarter"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
```

````

Comment: You really need to post some code to get help.

Comment: Why did i get down-voted on this? I tried so hard to be on 'StackOverflow' standards with my formatting, question structure and information.  Please leave a comment why your down-voting it  before downvoting

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I knew someone would because you hadn't posted any code.  I will look at the code you posted and see if I can be of any help at all.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I wasnt necessarily saying you down voted me, it was moreso directed at the community in general. Thank you for the help, let me know if i can add any assistance.  Thanks

Comment: I can tell you that part of your problem is all of the if statements.  These cause Angular to keep going through a digest cycle to test if the values have changed.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Thanks for the advice! I will get started on removing those ng-if's and replaceing them with ng-show, or something else if you suggest it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114074/discussion-between-rani-radcliff-and-jward01).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many if statements is probably causing Angular to keep running a digest cycle.  Try moving your logic to your controller.

```
if(thisdata == that){$scope.showThis = whatever}
```

Note:  Don't make 100 scopes either because you'll end up wit the same problem.  Make them the "value" on each item in in your repeat.  You can use `angular.forEach` to set the values in your controller.  That's all I have.  Hope this helps!  Happy coding!